# How to start a ros node

Tags: camera, nodes, ros

In ROS How do I start a ros node from the terminal? For example I'm looking to start the node `/camera/camera_nodelet_manager` but I have no idea how? Do I use rosrun and if so in what way?

Comment: I suggest you to start from the very basics here http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `rosrun [package_name] [node_name]` does the job. However, in many cases a node requires command-line arguments or parameters passed via *.[launch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) (XML) files .
You can start a node with a launch file by executing `roslaunch [package_name] [launch_file_name]`.

A Tab-Tab on `roslaunch [package_name]` will list you all launch files within the package.

Comment: Thanks I knew about this way but I thought there was a different way because from what I saw there was no way for me to execute `/camera/camera_nodelet_manager` what you have said does not work in this case.

Comment: @Giza: What exactly do you mean with `/camera/camera_nodelet_manager`? I guess _camera_ is the name of the package, then it should be `rosrun camera camera_nodelet_manager`

Comment: I think a look at the openni_launch launch files may help! 
use `roscd openni_launch` to get to the package. There you will find the launch files for the camera and manager nodelet.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, it seems like you're working with [openni_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch) based on the manager name `/camera/camera_nodelet_manager`. If you just want to get openni_launch going, you can do

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

The nodelet manager is [this executable](https://github.com/ros/nodelet_core/blob/indigo-devel/nodelet/src/nodelet.cpp). You can figure that out by looking at the [openni.launch file](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_launch/blob/indigo-devel/launch/openni.launch):

```
<!-- Start nodelet manager in top-level namespace -->
<arg name="manager" value="$(arg camera)_nodelet_manager" />
<arg name="debug" default="false" /> <!-- Run manager in GDB? -->
<include file="$(find rgbd_launch)/launch/includes/manager.launch.xml">
  <arg name="name"                value="$(arg manager)" />
  <arg name="debug"               value="$(arg debug)" />
  <arg name="num_worker_threads"  value="$(arg num_worker_threads)" />
</include>
```

It is launching a [second launch file](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rgbd_launch/blob/indigo-devel/launch/includes/manager.launch.xml) in the package [rgbd_launch](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rgbd_launch) that starts the nodelet executable:

```
<!-- Nodelet manager -->
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="$(arg name)" args="manager"
      output="screen" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
   <param name="num_worker_threads" value="$(arg num_worker_threads)" />
</node>
```

But in the general case, the suggestions of @cassinaj are good, `roslaunch`and `rosrun` are the command line capabilities of ROS to start executable code.